# View declared in DataTemplate keeps on creating when changing from Tab to Tab

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress, datatemplate

I have been following MVVM pattern to design my application. However, i have noticed a strange thing. I have a Tab control in which i have specified the ItemsSource as Binding for **WorkSpaces** from MainViewModel. In the Items, i have been adding different ViewModels. I have defined the DataTemplate for the ViewModel datatypes.

However, when i click on a tab, a new View is created everytime.

Sample code i am posting here.

```
<Grid.Resources>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type spavm:DashboardViewModel}">
  <UIDashboard:DashboardView/>
</DataTemplate>

</Grid.Resources>

<dx:DXTabControl Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" 
                         Name="MainContentTabs"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding WorkSpaces}"
                         ItemHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspaceItemTemplate}">
</dx:DXTabControl>
```

From the above, if i switch to any other tab and revisit my DashboardView, it is getting created again.

Am i missing anything?? I just need a single instance of the DashboardView. How can i achieve that.

Comment: This behavior is by design. The default WPF `TabControl` does that too. It destroys the entire Visual Tree and re creates it every time you switch tabs. It does so in order to save memory, by removing UI elements from the Visual Tree that are not visible or usable anyways.

Comment: BTW, I have edited your tags. If you are using DevExpress you need to tag your question `[devexpress]`

Comment: @HighCore Thanks for the information, but is there any alternative that i can use to show in a tabbed view. I want to preserve the visual state of my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, this is by design in DevExpress.  However, there is a property called `DestroyContentOnTabSwitching` that you can set to *false*.  [DX Documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfCoreDXTabControl_DestroyContentOnTabSwitchingtopic).

If your views are expensive to create you could also consider refactoring the expensive logic to cache it.

Comment: Apart from setting the DestroyContentOnTabSwitching we need to set TabContentCacheMode to All